# extract data from json

Tags: json, wcf

I have a json data coming from wcf  servicein jquery like this

GetBedTypeList1Result1 is function in wcf

```
{
    "GetBedTypeList1Result":[
        {"Code":23,"CompanyCode":null,"Decode":"1 Class New Born Bed","DivisionCode":0,"LocationCode":0,"admDueDepAmt":0,"bedTypeCode":0,"caseTypeCode":0,"caseTypeDecode":null,"ptnClassCode":0,"ptnClassDecode":null,"rsvDueDepAmt":0},
        {"Code":22,"CompanyCode":null,"Decode":"1st Class Bed","DivisionCode":0,"LocationCode":0,"admDueDepAmt":0,"bedTypeCode":0,"caseTypeCode":0,"caseTypeDecode":null,"ptnClassCode":0,"ptnClassDecode":null,"rsvDueDepAmt":0},
        {"Code":5,"CompanyCode":null,"Decode":"Classique Bed","DivisionCode":0,"LocationCode":0,"admDueDepAmt":0,"bedTypeCode":0,"caseTypeCode":0,"caseTypeDecode":null,"ptnClassCode":0,"ptnClassDecode":null,"rsvDueDepAmt":0}
    ],
    "strErrMsg":"Y",
    "chrErrFlg":"c"
}
```

I am calling service like below

```
         function CallWcfService() {
         //alert("CallWcfServicexxxx");
         jQuery.ajax
        (
         {

             type: Type,
             url: Url,
             data: parameters,
             contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
             dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
             cache: "false",
             crossDomain: true,   //Same result if i remove this line
             processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
             success: function (msg) 
             {
                 ServiceSucceeded(msg);
             },
             error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
         }
       );
     }



     function callService() 
     {
         DataType = "json";
         Type = "GET";
         var par = 4;
         parameters = null;
         Url = "http://192.168.2.42/CWSERVERWCF/bedtypemasterService.svc/GetBedTypeList?callback=?";
         parameters = "{'strErrMsg':'1'},{'chrErrFlg':'A'},{'pcompanycode':'0'},{'pdiv':'1'},{'ploc':'1'}";
        // alert(parameters);
         ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
         ProcessData = true;
         //alert("sssssasasadsds");
         CallWcfService();
     }
```

I am trying to fetch data but not getting lke below

```
   function ServiceSucceeded(result)
      {

        if (DataType == "json")
        {
           var obj =  jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(result)));
           for (var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++) 
            {

            }
         }
     }
```

In obj.length count of characters is coming  and jQuery.parseJSON(result) is not working

Please help

Comment: What in the world is going on with this line: `var obj =  jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(result)));`

Comment: if i do like this                                                   var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(result)))          then in alert(obj) I can view above json data given..need how to extract it jQuery.parseJSON(result) is not working

Comment: You don't need any of that. `result` is already an object. jQuery will have already parsed the JSON - that's why you define the data type. What you are doing is crazy. Just use `result` as the obj.

Comment: thanks this works for me 
              for (var i = 0; i < result.GetBedTypeList1Result.length; i++) 
              {
                  // ...do stuff
                 var bed = result.GetBedTypeList1Result[i].Code.toString();
                 alert(bed);
              }

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < result.GetBedTypeList1Result.length; i++) 
              {
                  // ...do stuff
                 var bed = result.GetBedTypeList1Result[i].Code.toString();
                 alert(bed);
              }  worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result is json there is no need to parse it in this way. jQuery.ajax will return a javascript object if the datatype is set to json.

So in your ServiceSucceeded function you may operate on the result variable directly. If you are trying to iterate over the bed types change your for loop to something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.GetBedTypeList1Result.length; i++) {
  // ...do stuff
  // var bed = result.GetBedTypeList1Result[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse(result)` instead of: `var obj =  jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(result)));`

Also, since you've mentioned the `dataType` as 'json' in your $.ajax call, your response should already be in JSON format with no parsing required.